# What is FormAuthentication mode and how do I implement it?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

FormAuthentication mode :

Suppose user request Application/LogOn , and LogOn page open in the browser ,
Now when user hit over login button , I check the username and password from DB values and If its correct then
redirect the user into Application/Home , If username and password not correct then show the alert box for 
showing message that credentials are not correct .

**Now my question is** :

1. what is FormAuthentication .
2. How its differ from my above mention Scenario.
3. How do I implement it into my application , what changes I have to make over webconfig 
   and on my code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [`nice guide`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs) to read about Forms Authentication.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.